# How can I make multiple page with mean.io?

Tags: express, single-page-application, mean-stack, mean.io

I want two different views. Like, one for admin panel and another for client side / front-end. How can I achieve that? There should be two different views overridden from system view or something like that.

Mean.io automatically loads all necessary js files which are included in all of those custom packages (other than assets directory). But I want to load the client side packages' resources / js files only  on client side and admin side packages' resources / js files only on admin side. So what should I do?